# Git auto completion behaving strangely

Tags: bash, git, autocomplete, alias

I'm seeing something very weird with `git` `alias`es. When using the tab key to get `git` commands auto completed I get `bash` errors. For example, if I type `git pu` to see all the options this happens:

```sh
$ git pu-bash: remote: command not found
-bash: -v: command not found
-bash: command substitution: line -327: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
-bash: command substitution: line -327: `| '
-bash: usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]: command not found
-bash: rev-parse: command not found
-bash: usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]: command not found
-bash: usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]: command not found
-bash: brname: command not found
-bash: brname: command not found
-bash: brname-trimmed: command not found
-bash: brname-trimmed: command not found
-bash: ls-files: command not found
-bash: @{u}: command not found
```

The terminal gets stuck few lines into the above output and after `^C`ing a couple of times all error lines are printed.

I'm not sure to which file the line numbers the errors are referring to as my `alias`s in `~/.gitconfig` end on line 174. I commented out any alias that had its name in the error list (ex `brname`), or used a `git` command that was listed (ex the builtin `rev-parse` is in the error). This was done till the error messages went away and and auto completion started working again.

So in the good state now if I type `git pu` and press tab I see the following:

```
$ git pu
pull   pull   push   push
```

Note that the responses are doubled here, and for any other input I press tab on.

One of the aliases I commented out to get to the good state is this:

```sh
brname-trimmed = !git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | tr -d '\n'
```

Let's say I'm on tab T1

1. If I open a new tab T2, uncomment the alias on T1, and save the file, I can use git with auto completion without any problems on T2.
2. If I uncomment the alias, save the file, and then open a new tab T2 and type `git pu` on T2 I see:

```
$ git pu-bash: : command not found
-bash: command substitution: line -166: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
-bash: command substitution: line -166: `&& '
```

line 166 of my `~/.gitconfig` doesn't have `:` nor `&&`, it's even commented out.

3. If I uncomment the alias, and change it to `xbrname-trimmed` (just adding an x to the beginning so it's a different word) auto completion works just fine regardless of when T2 is opened.

I'm working on a machine I haven't done dev work in months, so not sure when the issue occurred. The git version is `2.22.0`

Comment: The line numbers probably refer to the completion scripts and/or your various `.bash*` files. It's not at all clear to me what's going on, but I stay away from bash completion scripts. The ones included with Git work by actually running Git commands, and they're probably getting confused by some of your own aliases.

Comment: The exact same `~/.gitconfig` file worked just fine on another Mac for years. I copied the file from that machine here, but not sure if I did any dev work on this machine till now. I don't have the Mac I originally wrote the aliases, so can't compare the set ups.
I find it very strange that by adding that extra `x` auto completion became happy. Almost as if somehow there are certain words I can't use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first if the issue persists with Git 2.24, considering 2.23 and 2.24 have worked on the completion script.

Check also if your [Git bash completion is correctly installed](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion).

I added [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740722/git-auto-completion-behaving-strangely#comment103795383_58742786):

There a possibility for your `.bashrc/.profile` to have somehow an error which would manifest when running that completion bash script.
You need to test it with a minimal (almost empty) content for your `.bashrc/.profile` ("empty", beside defining at least the `$PATH`)

The [OP alamoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3411556/alamoot) confirms:

> Great call!
>   In my `~/.bash_profile` I was calling a script which was setting a custom `$BASH_COMPLETION` and `$BASH_COMPLETION_DIR`.
>   This custom script was part of and old "system setup" I don't need no more.
>   So taking it out I have got git completion working again.

Comment: The issue remains after upgrading to `git` version `2.24.0` and installing `bash-completion`

Comment: @alamoot Then, is there a possibility for your `.bashrc`/`.profile` to have somehow an error which would manifest when running that completion bash script? Can you test it with a minimal (almost empty) content for your `.bashrc`/`.profile`? ("empty", beside defining at least the `$PATH`)

Comment: Great call! In my `~/.bash_profile` I was calling a script which was setting a custom `$BASH_COMPLETION` and `$BASH_COMPLETION_DIR`. This custom script was part of and old "system setup" I don't need no more. So taking it out I have got `git` completion working again.